# Casting from C/C++ types to Objc types

Tags: objective-c, casting, bridge

I am currently working on a project that requires some objc bindings. Although I am not an iOs expert, I was doing quite good until now.

I need to cast some C++ types into Objc types :

```
std::streamsize read(uint32_t *buffer) {
    return _read(buffer, sizeof(uint32_t));
}

std::streamsize read(double *buffer) {
    return _read(buffer, sizeof(double));
}

std::streamsize read(std::string *buffer) {
    return _read(buffer, sizeof(std::string));
}

template<typename T>
std::streamsize _read(T *buffer, std::streamsize length) {
     NSString* buff = (__bridge NSString *)buffer;
    return [_memoryAdapter read:buff withLength:length];
}
```

I am getting these errors:

```
Incompatible types casting 'unsigned int *' to 'NSString *' with a __bridge cast.
Incompatible types casting 'double *' to 'NSString *' with a __bridge cast.
```

It seems my casts are almost all failing except the std::string one.

Am I using the __bridge wrong ? After some research, I did find it is used to cast C and C++ types into Objc. Could anyone give me an answer, a hint or/and an explanation about my mistake ? I also looked into stack overflow to any possible duplicate or further advices but couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance

Edit: I need to read into a buffer and store the bytes I read into the pointer, this is the reason why I am trying to cast it into NSMutableString.

```
- (NSInteger) read:(NSMutableString *)buffer withLength:(NSInteger)length {
const char* fileBytes = (const char*)[self._buffer bytes];
NSUInteger index;

for (index = 0; index< [self._buffer length]; index++)
{
    if (index >= self._cursor) {
        NSString *aByte  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", fileBytes[index]];
        [buffer appendString:aByte];
    }
    if (index >= self._cursor + length)
        break;
}
self._cursor += length;
return length;
```

}

Comment: Why do you think it's OK to cast a `unit32_t *` or a `double *` to an `NSString *`? That makes no sense.

Comment: Show the declaration for the read:withLength:` method you are calling on `_memoryAdaptor`.

Comment: Again, this makes no sense at all. `buffer` may actually be a `double *`. How can you possibly treat that as a mutable string that you can append to? It would seem you want to read `sizeof(double)` bytes from `self._buffer` into `buffer` to get a `double` value. Working with `NSString` (or `NSMutableString`) makes no sense for that.

Comment: I think I get it now and feel a bit stupid and ashamed. I never needed to cast these types (except for std::string maybe) since I could just append the values I read into the original buffer. I just needed to template my Objc methods instead of trying to cast my C++ parameter to make only one method on my Objc Code.

Comment: Please don't feel stupid or ashamed.  You're not expected to know the answer to your own question.  Tone on SO varies a lot between users, even for the same user based on his/her mood that day.  If you have this solved, post an answer showing the code working as you want it, explaining how it works.  The point is to make the q&a useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the NSNumber class cluster, which enables you to easily perform pointer to integer conversions from any type:

```
[[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:buffer] integerValue]
```

[image]

```
const char *index_pointer = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", index]] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```